# linux - Increase size sda

Tags: linux, debian

i try to add primary sda3 with 100gb

but only 1023 kb added on sda3

[See the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om1h0.png)

OS : Debian 9

Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB

```
Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048   499711   497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 41940991 41439234 19.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 41940991 41439232 19.8G 8e Linux LVM
```

Comment: This is because your sectors are trying to start at 499712 --  The next "start" sector group starts at 501758.  You need to choose the largest group of free space  ...  It looks like you are choosing free space "between" partitions ..

Comment: thanks @zak it's work, but i use bash script to create sda3, how can i find 41940992 for start sector ?

Comment: Look at the image ..  Your command line gives you options of which sectors to start and end on ..